# Nested Parse.Cloud.HttpRequests timeout error

Tags: javascript, callback, parse-platform, httprequest

Let's I have three methods in my cloud code, all of which invoke a Parse.Cloud.HttpRequest. All those methods, return a callback and I am executing the next function in the callback. This appears to give me a Code 124 and timeout error. Is there anyway to optimize this code?

Here's an example of how they are being called:

```
findMetroId(latitude,longitude,function(mI){
      mId = mI;
      //first httpRequest
      getArtistId(artist,function(aI){
      //second httpRequest
        id = aI;
        console.log("Testing values in main function: id = " + id + " mId = " + mId);
        compareDates(mId,id,latitude,longitude,function(myLink,status){
        //third httpRequest
          console.log("Is concert near? " + status);
          console.log("User to be Yo'd is " + username);
          if(status === true){
              console.log("Link is " + myLink);
              sendYo(username,myLink);//fourth httpRequest
          }else{
              //No concert is near to user
              sendYo(username,'http://concertalert.parseapp.com/no.html');
          }
        });


      });

    });
```

Comment: refer to [resource limits](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-resource), you need to analysis your request call and control it satisfied the limitation.

Comment: Try converting your `findMetroId` and `getArtistId` functions to promises, and then call them in parallel. There appears to be no dependency between them, so this _may_ help with the timeouts.

Comment: @rickerbh these methods use Parse.Cloud.httpRequest which return a Promise and the Promise is resolved with a Parse.Cloud.httpResponse...I don't have much experience with promises so I'm not sure how to convert the functions to promises

Comment: @user3140562 If they already return promises then all you need to do is execute them in parallel. You can check out https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-parallel for a guide on this.  If you need to get your functions to return the results as a promise, you can see [create and return](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-creation) a promise, and have it resolve when the HTTP response comes in and you parse out what you need to.